# Как убрать ненужные символы из переменной

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, sqlite3, telebot

```py
import telebot
import config
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread = False)
cursor = conn.cursor()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id
    sql = "SELECT admin FROM users WHERE user_id=?"
    cursor.execute(sql, [(user_id)])
    admin = cursor.fetchone()

bot.polling()
```

В этом коде, переменной admin присваивается значение 0 или 1, но на выводе получается `(0,)` или `(1,)`. Как мне убрать эти скобки и запятую, чтоб осталась только цифра. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эти скобки и запятая называются ***Кортежи (tuple)***. Для того, что бы ознакомиться с их свойствами, читайте учебник и/или документацию по Python в разделе [Операции с коллекциями](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#common-sequence-operations) или [Типы данных](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuples).

В вашем случае необходимо указать индекс значения в кортеже. В Python индексация коллекций начинается с `0`, то есть первый элемент имеет индекс `[0]`. Для того, что бы выполнить присвоение переменной, необходимо указать следующую строку кода:

```py
# заменить это
admin = cursor.fetchone()

# на это
result_query = cursor.fetchone()
admin = result_query[0]

# или это (более короткий вариант, но то же самое)
admin = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```